# iphone 5 views not sizing correctly with iphone 6 or 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

My Views are not auto zooming for iphone 6+ and 6,
I built the interface for iphone 5s and I disabled size classes.
All views are constrained through auto layout and a bunch of constraints but they look funny and dont seem to auto size correclty.

thoughts?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've had a problem on the simulator but it scales as expected on the device. Not sure why but I'd love to know too.

Comment: To my knowledge if you build for iOS 8 it automatically adjusts auto layout without scaling. The expectation is that users can choose between scaling and zooming through Settings, rather than at the app level.

Comment: Remus. That was it. Switching my phone to zoom made it better.  I guess I'll need to auto stretch my elements.